# Observable that delays a random time everytime the stream ends

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, reactive-programming

I need to create a bot that tweets with random intervals, like this:

```
wait 1 hour
tweets something
wait 5 hours
tweets something
wait 30 minutes
tweets something
wait 10 hours
tweets something
```

where the delay time is in between 10 hours or something like that

The problem with observables is that I need to generate these intervals and then feed it into the chain of observables. For example, I need to generate an array with all the delays and only them subscribe to it in order to tweet.

Isn't there a way to create an observable that emits a new item just when itself ends? For example:

```
Rx.Observable.just().timer(randomTime()).subscribe(emitObservableAgain());
```

I think this is somehow not what Observables are meant to do. Like... is it a good pratice to connect the end of a chain of observables to itself?

ALSO, how to import the rx.timer into nodejs? Importing just 'rx' (from npm) won't give me these functions

Answer (score 4):

You could use repeat:

```
Rx.Observable.just()
    .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.timer(randomTime()))
    .do(tweetMyThing)
    .repeat()
    .subscribe();
```

**Edit:** I Have added a live-script that shows how the stream works:

```js
// Helper-Methods to visualize the stream
function randomTime() {
    return ~~(Math.random() * 2000) + 50;
}

var lastReceivedEvent = +new Date();
function tweetMyThing(value) {
    console.log("Received after " + (+new Date() - lastReceivedEvent));
    lastReceivedEvent = +new Date();
}
// \end of helper-methods

// the stream
Rx.Observable.just()
    .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.timer(randomTime()))
    .do(tweetMyThing)
    .repeat(20)
    .subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: why switchMap? It worked but I wanted to know how exactly this is working. I can only think of repeat() as returning a new Observable but immediately emitting the last one so the subscribe can catch it. Is this it?

Comment: I've tried to understand it more, here it is: switchMap is like flatMap but it switches the stream immediately when called. Ok, so you emited nothing, switched to an Observable that emits a random time, made that observable trigger the do(tweetMyThing). I just didn't fully understand the repeat(). As I understood, it returns a stream that repeats (1x by default, I guess) the last stream. I just don't understand why it calls everything again and executes randomTime(). Why? For me repeat() would just re-emit the older stream with the time it was first conceived

Comment: Repeat repeats forever by default, and will repeat the whole stream, including the setting of a new random delay - have you tested this? - And switchMap and flatMap could be used both the same in this case: But when in doubt: use switchMap

Comment: yes I tested, but for me, once that delay time got generated, it'd be used in all repeats. Why this didn't happen? What's the internal working of the repeat() method?

Comment: then you must have done something differently, maybe you can post your stream if you have not taken the one I posted - I've added a live snipped to show you that the timer __is__ being set to a new value at every repeat - the only thing I could imagine is that you did not wrap your delay inside a switchMap ?